# How to free up Flash space by removing the bootloader on UNO?

Tags: bootloader, atmega328

In order to fit **maximum user program** into the chip, how to free up Flash space (0.5 kilo bytes for UNO, 2 KB pro Mini, 8KB for ATMega2560) by **removing the bootloader on Atmega328** (UNO, Pro Mini, or similar)?

What **software** development tools needed (like Atmel AVR Studio software or similar)?

What **hardware** flash writing / debug tools needed (like JTAG hardware programmer/debugger)?

How is the **procedure**? Where can I get **more information**.

Many thanks in advance.

edit: Update boot loader size for different boards

Comment: On UNO, the optiboot loader takes only 0.5KB not 2KB, so removing it will not be a big gain.

Comment: You'd need something like an `USBASP` programmer. You can use the regular Arduino IDE for programming, though you'd probably have to edit the boards.txt file a bit.

Comment: I looked at C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\broads.txt and, to my surprises, many boards use different boot loaders (hex file has different name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use an ISP programmer with avrdude. Perform a chip erase and then unprogram the `BOOTRST` fuse in the high fuse byte.